# Unique Identifier Across Tables

Tags: php, mysql, uniqueidentifier

First off: I've looked through similar questions and haven't found an answer.  Sorry if this is a repeat.

I'm pretty new to MySQL.

Let's say I have three tables: **Houses**, **Cars** and **Office Buildings**

All of these things have windows, so I'm going to need a **Windows** table as well.

Now, each Window can be up or down, double-pane or single-pane, etc.  Each Window has (correct me if it shouldn't) a unique ID.  Each window also needs to have a record of who has opened or closed it, which is why I figured a Windows table was necessary in the first place.

The question: Each Window must have a parent_id.  But the problem arises when there's a Car with an ID of XX, and an Office Building and House with the same ID.  When my page loads, how do I know where to place the window?

I assume there are many answers to this question... I'm looking for the best way.

P.S. Windows, Cars, Houses and Office Buildings are just illustrative examples.  Not my actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're saying is that each Window can belong to either a House, Car or Office Building? The established pattern for this is a polymorphic association, which is just a fancy word for "store the type of the related model together with its id":

```
Table `windows`
===============
id
parent_id
parent_model
...

window(1, 42, 'house', ...)
window(2, 7, 'car', ...)
...
```

This allows easy selective joining and querying:

```
SELECT * FROM `windows` JOIN `cars` ON
   (`windows`.`parent_model` = 'car' AND `windows`.`parent_id` = `cars`.`id`)
   ...
```

Comment: So I just store (in parent_model) the name of the table it pertains to?  If it's a house from the table houses, the parent_model is 'houses'?

Comment: Could this be a problem?  What if a query (for whatever reason) specifies a parent_model other than house, car or building?  How does the SQL know not to let this happen?

Comment: @Peter It just won't match any records then. That's only a problem in so far as you won't get any data back for that query.

Comment: A better (perfect, actually) example comes to mind: SO has votes for replies and posts.  Are all the votes stored in one table in this manner?  How is one user ensured one vote?

Comment: @Peter I don't know. Believe me when I say that this is an established pattern, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might also need one more table to map which window is mapped to which entity (Car / house / Office)

```
Table: window_mapping   
Columns: id (primary key / auto generated)
         Window_id (not null, ref to Window table primary key)
         Entity_id  (not null, ref to car /house /office table primary key) 
         entity _def (text with values, Car / house /office)
```

Or One more table approach would be

```
Table: window_mapping   
Columns: id (primary key / auto generated)
         Window_id (not null, ref to Window table primary key)
         house_id  (not null, ref to house table primary key) 
         car_id  (not null, ref to house table primary key) 
         office_id  (not null, ref to house table primary key)
```

I prefer 1'st though

If you expand your usecaes, I can try to help more

Comment: I think I see... the job of the window_mapping is to connect a window to its appropriate location?

Comment: Yes and to have better normalized data storage

Comment: This is basically a polymorphic many-to-many association. If a window can belong to more than one building/car/house, this is the right thing to do. If it's only a one-to-many association though, this is overkill.

Comment: Yes you are right. I assumed that he wants to have a many-many relationships